# Net Core Web Api and VueJS publish

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core-webapi

First sorry my english. Im developing a Webapi net core 2 app in the backend and a VueJs app in the front end.

- After run `npm run build` command I can see the vuejs app just created 1 Index.html file and a folder named static with all js, css, vendors inside.
- I want to run both project in the same domain:port. I just run `dotnet publish -c release` and I place in the folder wwwroot the vue app and then modified startup.cs as:

  `DefaultFilesOptions DefaultFile = new DefaultFilesOptions();
  DefaultFile.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
  DefaultFile.DefaultFileNames.Add("Index.html");
  app.UseDefaultFiles(DefaultFile);
  app.UseStaticFiles();`

This work perfect when I browse my webapi:5000 it's load automatically the Index.html, but my question is if this is a good practice. I dont care about compile both project and manually copy vue app inside wwwroot before the deploy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this I suggest you use this repository: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter

It implements a webpack middleware with hot reload. When build your net core api it runs a "pipeline" that install dependencies, build your client and copy the static files onto your wwwroot ready to work across your api.